# How do I run an asynchronous thread that only runs as long as the view that uses it is presented?

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous

How do I run an asynchronous thread that only runs as long as the view that uses it is presented?

I want the view to run this asynchronous thread. However, as soon as the view disappears, I want that thread to stop running. What's the best way to do this? I'm not sure where to start and might be thinking about this the wrong way. Nevertheless, what I described is how I want it to behave to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSOperation` to achieve what you want, NSOperation and NSOperationQueue are built on top of GCD. As a very general rule, Apple recommends using the highest-level abstraction, and then dropping down to lower levels when measurements show they are needed.

For example, You want to download images asynchronously when the view is loaded and cancel the task when the view is disappeared. First create a `ImageDownloader` object subclass to `NSOperation`. Notice that we check if the operation is cancelled twice, this is because the NSOperation has 3 states: `isReady -> isExecuting -> isFinish` and when the operation starts executing, it won't be cancelled automatically, we need to do it ourself.

```
class ImageDownloader: NSOperation {
    //1
    var photoRecord: NSURL = NSURL(string: "fortest")!

    //2
    init(photoRecord: NSURL) {
        self.photoRecord = photoRecord
    }

    //3
    override func main() {
        //4
        if self.cancelled {
            return
        }
        //5
        let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL:self.photoRecord)

        //6
        if self.cancelled {
            return
        }

    }
}
```

Then you can use it like: `downloader.cancel()`, `downloader.start()`. Notice that we need to check if the operation is cancelled in the completion block.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let downloder = ImageDownloader(photoRecord: NSURL(string: "test")!)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloder.completionBlock = {
            if self.downloder.cancelled {
                return
            }
            print("image downloaded")
        }
        //Start the task when the view is loaded
        downloder.start()    
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        //Cancel the task when the view will disappear
        downloder.cancel()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once **DetailViewController** is presented, the **asyncOperation method** will be executed asynchronously.

**Note:** currently the **asyncOperation method** is executed every second so if you want the method to be called only once, you must change the **repeats property** to **false**.

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
  // timer that will execute
  // asynchronously an operation
  var timer: NSTimer!

  // counter used in the async operation.
  var counter = 0

  // when view is about to appear
  override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    // setting up the timer
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
      1.0,
      target: self,
      selector: #selector(asyncOperation),
      userInfo: nil,
      repeats: true //set up false if you don't want the operation repeats its execution.
    )
  }

  // when view is about to disappear
  override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    // stopping the timer
    timer.invalidate()
  }

  // async operation that will
  // be executed
  func asyncOperation() {
    counter += 1
    print("counter: \(counter)")
  }
}
```

---

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/

Result:

[image]